# android - draw slope / slant line on a textview

Tags: android

[image]

hi,
I'm trying to implement something similar to the image attached. I have two textviews one on top of the other and i want their borders to look like the one in the image. I was able to draw rounded corners by setting the cornerradii of the GradientDrawable but i have no clue as in how to draw the slope on the right side of the first textview. 
Any help on how to do this is much appreciated!!
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would in this case do the graphics in a some graphics editing program (Photshop, GIMP or Inkscape for example). Two different drawings, one for the top part and one for the bottom. Then convert the drawings to [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) to be used as backgrounds for the text views. Since this type of drawable can be made larger or smaller depending on the length of the text in the TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent background image instead of drawing the background. Else you can use the canvas.

Edit : bad  image example :-)

[image]